# EditText masking with dash

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I want to create a mask with EditText, the goal is to have four (4) dashes at the beginning and when the user types each dashes will be replaced by the user input. I am thinking of using `splice` and `replace` but having a difficulty of proper handling with the backspace to delete inputs as well. What is the best approach for this?

This is how it should look like this
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFjJO.png)

Now the number of input is not limited to four (4) character as it has a maximum of 50 characters. So to demonstrate it should look like this:

Eg.

1. A - - -
2. A B - -
3. A B C -
4. A B C D
5. A B C D E and so on

Comment: try using `onTextChangedListener` and implementing `aftertTextChanged` method. I've had implemented similar functionality for edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Already managed it myself by this approach. If you have or can optimize this solution feel free to answer.

```kotlin
var isProgrammatic = false
val origTextSize = 36f
val totalDashes = "- - - -".split(" ").size
    
voucher_input.doAfterTextChanged {
    if (!it.isNullOrBlank()) {
        //No dashes here
        var placeHolder = it.filterNot { c -> "-".contains(c)}.toString()
    
        Log.wtf("Plain", placeHolder)
    
        if (placeHolder.isBlank()) {
            voucher_input.text = null //Use hint
            return@doAfterTextChanged
        }
    
        if (isProgrammatic) {
            isProgrammatic = false
            return@doAfterTextChanged
        }
    
        if (placeHolder.length < 4){
            val cursor = placeHolder.length
            val numDash =  totalDashes - placeHolder.length
    
            var dashes = ""
            for (i in 1..numDash)
                dashes += "-"
    
            placeHolder += dashes
    
            Log.wtf("Dashes", placeHolder)
    
            isProgrammatic = true
            voucher_input.setText(placeHolder) //Modified input
            voucher_input.setSelection(cursor) //Place cursor near at the end of alphanumeric
    
            return@doAfterTextChanged
        }
        else if (placeHolder.length == 4) {
            isProgrammatic = true
            voucher_input.setText(placeHolder) //Start normal input
            voucher_input.setSelection(voucher_input.text!!.length) //Place cursor at the end
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).